# Python Pillow Image combination

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to combine a list of images on a page, with a given height, so that they flow first down the page, then across, e.g.:

```
Image1 Image4 Image7
Image2 Image5 Image8
Image3 Image6 Image9
```

The maximum number of columns is 3. The issue is that these images are passed in dynamically, but all have a fixed width i.e. they can only span 1/2/3 columns so something like this can happen:

```
Image1 Image4-Image4
Image2-Image2-Image2
Image3 Image5 Image6
```

Also, the height of each image in my list is variable, meaning that there isn't a set number of rows. So if an image were to exceed the page or overlap another image. it has to also be stored for later. Blank spaces are allowed, e.g.:

```
Image1        Image4
Image2-Image2 Image4
Image2-Image2 Image5
```

In the example above Image3 took up the entire page, or maybe ~3/4 of the page, meaning it wouldn't fit, so it is kept for another new page.

How can I achieve this method of combining images?

Comment: Is the order in which they appear on the page important? For example, can I choose to output all the 3-column wide images first, then all the 2-column wide images each accompanied by a 1-column image, and finally rows with three 1-column wide images till I run out?

Comment: @MarkSetchell No, the order IS important, thanks :).

Comment: So why is Image-3 allowed to be after Image5 in your last example please?

Comment: Furthermore, why does Image-4 come before Image-2 in your last example, because Image-2 would have fitted before Image-4 in that first row?

Comment: So order is important, but because image 3 was too big it can be moved to another page, but if the next picture can fit then it can just fill the empty slot, does that make sense?

Comment: that was just to show that the height can vary, so image4 is taking up 2 of my "imaginary rows"

Comment: So there are only 3 possible widths for any image, and only 3 possible heights. Is that correct?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Yes, my solution is limited to always making a grid of the same number of tiles as specified by the tiles argument. So if one takes up the full width, two others will still be by its side. The only way to do that, is by planning each output and use +-append (or -mosaic with -page offsets for placement)

Comment: @fmw42 Is there a way to automate this process? Because with the code you provided, as I understand it, I have to specify the grid for every group of images I want to combine. But as I said the amount of images is dynamic. I currently have about ~400 images(this number will increase), I was hoping for a less tedious solution haha. So can this be automated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a complex set of rules. I think you'll probably need to write some code if you want that exact behaviour.

I'm trying to avoid doing any actual work, so I wrote a little python to lay out pages for you:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import math
import pyvips

column_width = 256
row_height = 256
background_colour = 255 # you could use eg. [128, 255, 128] as well

# pop enough tiles from the argument to fill a page
def layout(tiles):
    # we insert an image (at its top-left), or "x" if a tile is covered by an
    # image up and left of itself
    page = [[None for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]

    # where we put the next tile
    current_x = 0
    current_y = 0

    # loop to fill page
    page_filled = False
    while not page_filled:
        # used up all the tiles?
        if tiles == []:
            break

        this_tile = tiles[0]
        tiles_across = math.ceil(this_tile.width / column_width)
        tiles_down = math.ceil(this_tile.height / row_height)

        # image too large for page
        if tiles_across > 3 or tiles_down > 3:
                raise Exception(f"tile too large - {this_tile}")

        # loop to find the next free space this tile fits
        while True:
            # too tall for this column?
            if tiles_down > 3 - current_y:
                current_y = 0
                current_x += 1

            # too wide for this row? 
            if tiles_across > 3 - current_x:
                # we've filled the page
                page_filled = True
                break

            # is this set of tiles clear?
            all_clear = True
            for y in range(tiles_down):
                for x in range(tiles_across):
                    if page[current_y + y][current_x + x]:
                        all_clear = False

            if all_clear:
                break

            # try the next slot down
            current_y += 1

        # did we find a spot?
        if not page_filled:
            # place the tile here and mark the spaces it covers in the page
            for y in range(tiles_down):
                for x in range(tiles_across):
                    page[current_y + y][current_x + x] = "x"
            page[current_y][current_x] = this_tile
            tiles.pop(0)

    # the page has filled -- draw!
    image = pyvips.Image.black(3 * column_width, 3 * row_height) \
            + background_colour
    for y in range(3):
        for x in range(3):
            if isinstance(page[y][x], pyvips.Image):
                image = image.insert(page[y][x], \
                        x * column_width, y * row_height)

    return image

# a source of tiles .. we just load the command-line arguments
all_tiles = [pyvips.Image.new_from_file(filename, access="sequential")
             for filename in sys.argv[1:]]

page_number = 0
while all_tiles != []:
    filename = f"page-{page_number}.jpg"
    print(f"generating {filename} ...")
    page = layout(all_tiles)
    page.write_to_file(filename)
    page_number += 1
```

You can run it like this:

```
$ ./layout.py ~/pics/shark.jpg ~/pics/k2.jpg ~/pics/shark.jpg ~/pics/shark.jpg ~/pics/shark.jpg ~/pics/shark.jpg ~/pics/shark.jpg ~/pics/shark.jpg
generating page-0.jpg ...
generating page-1.jpg ...
$
```

It seems to work for me and implements all your rules (I think). I used [pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/) to do the page rendering because I'm familiar with it, but it'd be simple to swap it out for something else.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! Exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can make ImageMagick put the images vertically first in montage by a trick. Transpose the images first, montage, then transpose the result.

```
convert logo3.jpg lena2.jpg hatching.jpg zelda3.jpg -transpose miff:- |\
montage - -geometry +2+2 -tile 2x2 miff:- |\
convert - -transpose montage_columns.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will try this out soon

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care the order of the images in the result nor the grid numbers and just want the best fit for a given output size, then ImageMagick has a new feature for doing that.  See ASHLAR:ouput.png at https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#pseudo

```
magick lena.jpg barn.jpg mandril3.jpg monet2.jpg zelda1.jpg redhat.jpg -background black -define ashlar:best-fit=true ASHLAR:x.png[600x400+0+0]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in Python as a subprocess call to ImageMagick montage as follows:

```
import subprocess

cmd = '/usr/local/bin/montage lena.jpg house.jpg boats3_small.jpg barn.jpg cameraman.jpg mandril3.jpg monet2.jpg zelda1.jpg redhat.jpg -tile 3x3 -geometry +0+0 -gravity north -background black montage.jpg'

subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Fred, I don't think this will work if some images are triple or double width. I think it will always put 3 images across, whereas it should just put a triple width image on its own. And a double-width image should be paired with a single. I think ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Can the images flow by column and not row? I see you put lena.jpg -> house.jpg -> boat.jpg, it's going horizontally, but I need it to flow vertically.